# when should i delete old pages after .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just changed my site from .htm files to .php files with the same name and used a redirect in my .htaccess file which worked great, when is it safe to delete the .htm version of the files?  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your htaccess redirectes all the traffic to the corresponding .php files, you're save to delete them since they're not accessed anymore.

*If* the links are still valid however it may be nice to keep them so that you're not creating a ton of dead links on other sites (if your directory is overfilled, you can automatically redirect *.htm to `/archiv/$uri` for example). Also, a backup is a good idea in case something malfunctions or you need to roll back.

Comment: If this was what you're looking for, please mark it as the correct answer ;)